# Have Celery broadcast return results from all workers

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

Is there a way to get all the results from every worker on a Celery Broadcast task? I would like to monitor if everything went ok on all the workers. A list of workers that the task was send to would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, that is not easily possible.

But you don't have to limit yourself to the built-in amqp result backend,
you can send your own results using Kombu (http://kombu.readthedocs.org),
which is the messaging library used by Celery:

```
from celery import Celery
from kombu import Exchange

results_exchange = Exchange('myres', type='fanout')

app = Celery()

@app.task(ignore_result=True)
def something():
    res = do_something()
    with app.producer_or_acquire(block=True) as producer:
        producer.send(
            {'result': res},
            exchange=results_exchange,
            serializer='json',
            declare=[results_exchange],
        )
```

`producer_or_acquire` will create a new `kombu.Producer` using the celery
broker connection pool.

Comment: So if I understand correctly you make the consumer (task executer) a producer for sending back the results? Now it really gets complicated :)